# ANgular 5 app deployment

Tags: angular, hosting

I have deployed angular 5 app to hosting. i have deployed project with `ng build --prod --build-optimizer`, but in server rout links doesn't work.(only works main page). Other components doesn't.

Here my app.routing.modules.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'main', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'main', component: MainComponent},
      {path: 'cs', component: CsSetkaComponent},
      {path: 'dota', component: DotaSetkaComponent},
      {path: 'dota/:id', component: DotaDesComponent},
      {path: 'cs/:id', component: CsDesComponent},
      {path: 'news', component: NewsComponent},
      {path: 'news/:id', component: NewDesComponent},
      {path: 'gallery', component: GalleryComponent}
    ]},
  {path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent},
  {path: 'panel', component: AdminPanelComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: '**', component: ErrorComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,
    {
      enableTracing: true
    })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here my home.component.html

```
<div class="bg">
<!--Header-->
<div class="header">
  <div class="w3layouts_header_left">
    <div class="top-nav-text">
      <p>Позвоните нам: <span class="call">+99899 839 02 55</span></p>
      <p>Свяжитесь с нами по электронной почте : <span class="mail"><a href="mailto:nshaxrizod@mail.ru">info@example.com</a></span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="w3_navigation">
  <nav class="navbar-default navbar navbar-left navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="w3_navigation_pos">
      <h1><a href=""><span>Toshkent-Cup</span></a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation_pos collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <nav class="text-center effect">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav mr-auto">
          <li class="active"><a href="" class="scroll"><span data-hover="Главная">Главная</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="/home/news" ><span data-hover="Новости">Новости</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="/home/main#about" du-smooth-scroll class="scroll"><span data-hover="О нас">О нас</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="/home/main#tournament" du-smooth-scroll="tournament" class="scroll"><span data-hover="Турнир">Турнир</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="/home/main#mail" class="scroll"><span data-hover="Контакты">Контакты</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="/home/gallery" class="scroll"><span data-hover="Галерея">Галерея</span></a></li>


        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>


<router-outlet></router-outlet>

</div>
```

When i am clicking `<li><a href="/home/gallery" class="scroll"><span data-hover="Галерея">Галерея</span></a></li>` it gives me 404 error

> How I can solve it?

Comment: Which hosting (provider) are you using?

Comment: [link](http://ahost.uz)

Comment: Which server are you using for hosting the application? NodeJS Server, Apache? How do you host this application? For adding angular routing you need to add some middleware.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues on that approach.

First, when using angular router, you should not use the `href` property on your `a` tags. Instead you should use the `routerLink` property like:

```
routerLink="/home/news"
```

otherwise your app is no longer a single page application as you are requesting a new page to the server at every link click (and the pages you are requesting does not even exist in your server).

The second issue that i believe you might be facing is the fact that your server should **always** respond with the index.html file when hosting an Angular app. So you need to configure it to send the index.html upon 404 response. This happens because the index is the only page your server knows, and thus, when you request for a /home/news page it does not know the file and respond with a 404.